# Go Generate "executable not found in path"

Tags: linux, go, github-actions

I am using a go generate command (inside a github action) and it is saying that none of the libraries I am using for the executable are found in $PATH

so lets say I have this code.go

```
package code

// go:generate generator
struct Code {}
```

When I run this normally it works just fine with zero issues.

But when I run it in github actions (the local act library) it says:

```
running "generator": exec: "generator": executable file
 not found in $PATH
```

When I echo $PATH:
".....:/home/runner/go/bin/:/home/runner/go/bin/generator"

And the executable is found in path in the step right before I run generate

```
  - name: RUN GENERATOR
    run: generator  # this works just find

  - name: GENERATE NEW CODE
    working-directory: ./code
    run: |
      sudo go generate -v ./...
```

Edit:
Additional note:
Paths are identical between sudo and non sudo command
however `run: sudo generator` does not work and no longer finds the file

For anyone that stumbles upon this it seems that my problem is related to act and how it handles the difference between linux and windows clients:
https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/437
https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/491

Hopefully these are both solved to help fix this issues I had with permissions

My solution was to make an environment variable called "$SUDO" filled with sudo and turned it off if was in an environment where it could safely write files without issue

Comment: Is the binary at `/home/runner/go/bin/generator/generator`? If the binary is at `/home/runner/go/bin/generator` then your `PATH` should just have `/home/runner/go/bin` as `PATH` is a list of *directories*, not a list of *executables*.

Comment: Yes it is.
It is at both and as I have said it executes just fine outside of the go generate command.
It only fails when executed within go generate

Comment: You are using go modules?

Comment: Does your go PATH feature in `sudo bash -c "echo $PATH"` when you become `runner`?

Comment: @tink Yes the path is exactly the same when running as sudo or non sudo

But you are correct that the executeable is not found if i directly do
`sudo generator`

Comment: When you say `directly` ... as which user are you doing that?

Comment: Honestly not sure.

This isn't normal linux it is whatever user "github actions" provides
for example running "sudo su" just freezes github actions until the timeout
so user based ideas may not be the best way to go about it
But unfortnately I do have to run go generate with sudo otherwise I get a permission denied error

Comment: @tink I ran
`echo "$(whoami)"` and `sudo echo "$(whoami)"`
both were "runner"

Comment: Does the `permission denied` tell you which file/directory it's grumpy with?  You may be better off fixing ownerships/permissions than carry on futzing w/ sudo which would only compound the problem by generating more files owned by `root`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236573/discussion-between-dtracers-and-tink).